# Using .Net Variables in Google Analytics.js Event Tracking Send

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to send Event Tracking values using labels set by code behind variables. It all renders correctly on the page, however, it does not actually track those events. The dynamic events do not display in GA under the Events area, but the hardcoded "Download" event does.

If I try this, only the first "Download" event shows in GA:

```
$('#DownloadButton').on('click', function () {
      var s1 = "<%= Var1 %>";
      var s2 = "<%= Var2 %>";
      var s3 = "<%= Var1 %> | <%= Var2 %>";

      ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'Download');

      //these next variable labels never are received in GA
      ga('send', 'event', 'cat1', 'v1', s1);
      ga('send', 'event', 'cat2', 'v2', s2);
      ga('send', 'event', 'cat3', 'both', s3);

});
```

If I put the server vars inline, then the "Download" and the Var1 get sent, but not the last two:

```
$('#DownloadButton').on('click', function () {

      ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'Download');
      ga('send', 'event', 'cat1', 'v1', "<%= Var1 %>");

      //these last two never get received by GA
      ga('send', 'event', 'cat2', 'v2', "<%= Var2 %>");
      ga('send', 'event', 'cat3', 'both', "<%= Var1 %> | <%= Var2 %>");

});
```

It seems like it breaks after it hits the end of "<%= Var1 %>".

Var1 is a name like "Gala Apple" and renders correctly on the page:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'sheet', 'Side1', "Gala Apple");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GA has this tool on the chrome store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

It allows you to see what it is sending to the GA servers. To use it, open chrome, enable the debugger, then open your console tab in the developer tools. When you load the page and trigger events, it should log them to the window.

If you watch it when clicking the `#DownloadButton` it should shed some light on what's happening. My guess is, it's not reaching those lines because your button has another `click` handler attached to it that changes the page location, or does something to stop execution. Since js is single-threaded, depending on how long it takes, it may leave the page before it can finish sending your other tracking beacons.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. When the download button is clicked, I see all four send messages begin. Then the page calls Response.End() to serve up the downloaded file. At that point, the remaining sends keep spinning, but never finish. What can I do since this is async?

Comment: The short answer: not much. You can use js on your downloadbutton to do something like `setTimeout(myFunc, 100);` which will delay execution of `myFunc` for 100 milliseconds. That will work for most broadband users, but it probably will leave some slower connection users with half-finished tracking beacons. Another option is to not change the page when `#DownloadButton` is clicked, but since you did not float that as an option originally, I am guessing that that is more difficult to do with your current setup.